# python crawling text from <em></em>

Tags: python, text, web-crawler

[image]

[image]

Hi, I want to get the text(number 18) from em tag as shown in the picture above.
When I ran my code, it did not work and gave me only empty list. Can anyone help me? Thank you~

here is my code.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://blog.naver.com/kwoohyun761/221945923725'
html = urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

likes = soup.find_all('em', class_='u_cnt _count')

print(likes)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you disable javascript you'll see that the like count is loaded dynamically, so you have to use a service that renders the website and then you can parse the content.

You can use an API: https://www.scraperapi.com/

Or run your own for example: https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash

EDIT:

First of all, I missed that you were using urlopen incorrectly the correct way is described here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html . Assuming you are using python3, which seems to be the case judging by the print statement.

Furthermore: looking at the issue again it is a bit more complicated. When you look at the source code of the page it actually loads an iframe and in that iframe you have the actual content: Hit ctrl + u to see the source code of the original url, since the side seems to block the browser context menu.

So in order to achieve your crawling objective you have to first grab the initial page and then grab the page you are interested in:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# original url
url = "https://blog.naver.com/kwoohyun761/221945923725"

with urlopen(url) as response:
   html = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

iframe = soup.find('iframe')

# iframe grabbed, construct real url
print(iframe['src'])
real_url = "https://blog.naver.com" + iframe['src']

# do your crawling
with urlopen(real_url) as response:
   html = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

likes = soup.find_all('em', class_='u_cnt _count')

print(likes)
```

You might be able to avoid one round trip by analyzing the original url and the URL in the iframe. At first glance it looked like the iframe url can be constructed from the original url.

You'll still need a rendered version of the iframe url to grab your desired value.

I don't know what this site is about, but it seems they do not want to get crawled maybe you respect that.

Comment: thanks. I am still struggling to figure out how to pick out the number.
If you could give me a sample code, that would be great.

Comment: I extended my post

Comment: thanks for the code and help. I will try myself again.